# Linq to SQL - Group by WorkWeek (ISO_WEEK)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there an equivlent way to do this query with Linq? It is the ISO_WEEK that is tripping me up.
Table is simple. Id is an int and EndTime is a datetime.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Total, DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EndTime) AS WorkWeek
FROM Items
GROUP BY DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, EndTime)
ORDER BY WorkWeek DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the **DatePart** function of **SqlFunctions** Class in this namespace **System.Data.Objects.SqlClient**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was another location for sql functions. I was looking at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.